# Getopt returns -1 yet it has valid data

Tags: c, getopt

I'm running my program in GDB to determine why getopt is returning -1, and I can see that it clearly has valid data. I'm not getting argv/argc from the command line of the program, I'm generating it myself, but it's still clearly valid data.

The (relevant) code:

```
    char* argv[4];                                                                                                                         
    printf("calling create_argv\n");                                                                                                       
    int argc = create_argv(argstring, argv, 4);                                                                                            
    int opt;                                                                                                                               
    int myBuf = 0, total_mbufs = 0;                                                                                                        
    bufs_list* bufToUse = einf->bufs_head;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "f:t:")) != -1){                                                                                              
    printf("opt is %s\n", opt);                                                                                                            
    switch(opt){                                                                                                                                   
        case 'f':                                                                                                                                      
        fd = fopen(optarg, "r");                                                                                                               
        break;                                                                                                                         
        case 't':                                                                                                                                      
        fsize = atoi(optarg);                                                                                                                  
        break;                                                                                                                         
        default: break;                                                                                                                
    }                                                                                                                              
}
```

create_argv: (working from what I can tell with GDB)

```
int create_argv(char* string, char* argv[], int nargs){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    int idx = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    char* s;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    char* p;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    printf("in create_argv\n");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    for (s = string, p = string; *s != '\0' && *s != '\n'; s++){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        printf("%c\n", *s);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        if (*s == ' '){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
            *s = '\0';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            argv[idx++] = p;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
            printf("%s\n", p);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            p = ++s;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            if (idx == nargs) return idx; //bail out if we can't fit any more                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    *s = '\0';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    argv[idx++] = p;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    printf("%s\n", p);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    p = ++s;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    return idx; //equivalent to argc
}
```

So gdb says that everything is in perfect working order:

```
(gdb) p opt
$2 = -1
(gdb) p argc
$3 = 2
(gdb) p argv
$4 = {0x7a9935 "-f", 0x7a9938 "file.txt", 0x2f76006f666e692f <Add
```

(argv[2] is invalid, but that's fine because argc is only 2).

So what's wrong with getopt? It clearly has a valid argc, a valid argv, yet it refuses to acknowledge that what it's got is valid data.

Edit: the output shows that the while loop never runs -

```
calling create_argv
in create_argv
-
f

-f 
i
l
e
.
t
x
t
file.txt
no file loaded (did you specify -f filename?). Refusing to load an empty file
```

Comment: It doesn't look like `getopt` returns -1 on error, but rather when it reaches the end of the arguments. Here is the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) for `getopt`. Can you add the output of your program to the question?

Comment: @GuyMarino output added - the while loop never runs, despite there being arguments there

Comment: Good point on the printf. I don't think that would be causing this issue, but it's a good thing to remember

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure if this will fix it, but try a do-while loop with the negative one condition and print the values of `optopt` and `optarg`. They might contain what you're looking for. If you don't want to rewrite your code, just check them in the debugger after the loop runs.

Comment: optarg and optopt are both 0 immediately after the loop (the failed first iteration) runs

Comment: Okay, one more thing you may want to try is setting the first value in `argv` to some unnecessary value. The reason I say this is because `argv` usually takes the form of `[program_name] [args...]` and the function may trim the 0th element.

Comment: @GuyMarino I hadn't thought of that, and that's likely what's happening, will try that and report back

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235668/discussion-between-guy-marino-and-brydon-gibson).

Comment: It is *not* fine that `argv[2]` is invalid when `argc == 2`.  `getopt()` is within its rights to assume that `argv[argc] == NULL`, as that is guaranteed to be the case for the arguments to the initial call to `main()`.  If that is not true of the arguments presented to `getopt()` then they do not satisfy the preconditions of that function.

Comment: @JohnBollinger good note - create_argv will have to terminate the array with null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting this here for later, but `getopt` expects the first value of `argv` to be the program name, and trims it without parsing the value. This means you'll need to prepend a dummy program name if you're generating the `argv` values yourself.